# Generate Stripe Subscription Link

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to create a payment link for a subscription in the backend and send it to the client without having any frontend site.

```
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({

        metadata: {
            author_id: "author_id",
            custom_id: "custom_id",
        },
    ....
}
```

First I created a customer, using my app specific credentials. Then I want to generate a link using this custome id, but I'm kinda confused how to make it work,

Stripe documentation shows something like this,

```
  await stripe.paymentLinks.create({
    line_items: [{price: price_id, quantity: 1}],
  });
```

But it creates a completely new product price.

Is there any way to create a link using pre made product price id and customer metadata using Stripe NodeJS backend?

Comment: Also, your question is confusing. Your code demonstrates passing an existing `price_xxx` object ID to the creation call, yet you claim the Payment Link 'creates a completely new product price'. This is not how that should work. Can you clarify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a pre-existing Customer object (`cus_xxx`) when creating a Payment Link. The default behaviour for Payment Links infer that a new Customer object be created depending on other parameters set on the Payment Link, as noted in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-customer_creation):

> The Checkout Session will only create a Customer if it is required for Session confirmation. Currently, only subscription mode Sessions require a Customer.